# can you make dua inside of salat in any language if you are not a native?

Tags: salat, dua

Is it okay to make dua inside of salat like while prostrating or in tahsahhud in any language that you speak if you do not know Arabic?

Comment: This is related if not a duplicate https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/is-it-acceptable-to-perform-istakhara-in-english-if-so-how

Comment: I am sorry but the question answer you mentioned does not answer this specific question in any way. what I wanted to know is that, is it valid to say any other language inside of salat for making dua? I have heard somewhere that speaking any other language is not valid inside salat but Im not sure. Thats why I needed the clarification. Thank you

Comment: The statement about dua' in that answer is universal, beside I wonder if your question is not answered somewhere on the site!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can speak any language when making du'a in salat. We are recommended to make du'a to Allah frequently, but never is it stated that this must only be in Arabic. Each nation was sent messengers who spoke their language. Other books were sent in, for example the Torah, in Hebrew not Arabic.

It is recommended to learn Arabic in order to study the Quran in its original language, as it is the final message from Allah, the final Book sent to humankind, and has not been changed or adulterated. Meanings can be lost or misconstrued in translation, so it is best if more Muslims learn Arabic to contribute to their knowledge. Also it is best to learn a few basic surahs of the Quran to read in salat, because this is the language in which it came, and the language of Prophet Mohammad.

But this does not mean you are prohibited from calling upon Allah in your own language including in salat. Also you do not have to say your du'a aloud in that case either. But if you so it would seem a not-too-loud approach would be best. (The Quran recommends this.)

And of course, Allah hears and understands all things and all people, regardless of language. And you are ultimately praying and making salat to Allah with no intermediary. No translation therefore required. Allah created people of many nations and languages that we might know each other; it would make no sense to handicap so many Muslims in their salat.