# Is it compulsory to recite short duas in Arabic?

Tags: arabic, dua, muslim-practices

I wanted to know if the short duas, like while travelling, while getting on a vehicle, while entering/exiting toilets, making decision for wudu/salat, etc are compulsory to be said in Arabic or could it be said in English or some local language?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Would you mind reading my answer on [Is it acceptable to perform istikhara in English if so how?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/is-it-acceptable-to-perform-istakhara-in-english-if-so-how/36677#36677) and inform  us whether this answers your question or not!

Comment: It is best to recite in the language you can understand because at that time you know what you are saying. So better to learn Arabic, so you can understand what you are praying.