# Can I make Dua in English, must it be a Surah from Quran?

Tags: salat, dua, english

I don't speak Arabic, therefore if I'm making dua to Allah does it always have to be a surah from the Quran or can I make dua in English anytime too? For example: “O’ Allah please help me to do well on my test tomorrow”, or will I have to find a surah that is related to that?

And what about during sujood, can I make English dua during sujood or does it have to be a surah from the Quran?

Comment: You are asking about Dua during Salah?

Comment: Both-during salah and not during salah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it acceptable to perform istakhara in English? If so, how?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/is-it-acceptable-to-perform-istakhara-in-english-if-so-how) the answer there covers this question!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pray (salat), you should speak in Arabic, because Allah wants muslims to pray like each other ( it's a kind of alliance). But if you want Allah to bless you( dua),he will help you, even if you do not ask him in Arabic. It can be in any language.