# making dua in salah

Tags: salat, dua, language, sajda

can I make dua in prostration in mother tongue? if I can then when inside in salah or I should make extra prostration/sperate prostration without salah to make dua? can I make dua in prostration of fard sunnah and nafl salah too? can I make my own dua in prostration besides quraan sunnah duas? and last can I make dua in last rakat of salah after finishing durud? if I can then can I make the dua in my own native language? cause I don't know arabic and can I make dua what I need in that part? or quraan sunnah duas?

Comment: Be aware that these are several questions which should be asked separately after a prior research at least on our site (see in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions). As for the question about asking performing du'a in your own language I think this is already covered in [Is it acceptable to perform istikhara in English if so how?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/is-it-acceptable-to-perform-istakhara-in-english-if-so-how).