# Can I make dua in English?

Tags: salat, dua, english

I am a non arabic speaking Muslim. I’ve memorized all of the recitations in arabic for the salah but I’m just wondering if it’s required to make the dua at the end of prayer in arabic also or can I do that in english?

Comment: This should have been covered in [Is it acceptable to perform Istikhara in English if so how?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/is-it-acceptable-to-perform-istakhara-in-english-if-so-how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to make dua both during, and after salah, but the duas just before you end your salah must be established from the Quran or sunnah of Nabi sallAllahu alyhi wasallam, while duas made after salah have no such restrictions, and can be made in any language.