# Salah al-istikhara

Tags: dua, istikharah

Salam alekom guys , so as everyone knows the salah is 2 rakkat and we recite the dua after sallah. The question  is  , I have a hard time reading in Arabic and I’ve been doing my dua in English but then I knew that it’s only for the people that don’t know Arabic at all . I do know Arabic but have a very hard time in reading it , so it is acceptable if I could still read it in English?

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question.

Comment: Salam and welcome to ISlamSE theQ&A site about islam. Isn't your inquiry already covered in [Is it acceptable to perform istikharah in English, if so how?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/is-it-acceptable-to-perform-istakhara-in-english-if-so-how)